# 52 cards are spread on the table,probability of the second ace to be right after the first ace

Tags: probability

52 cards are being spread on the table, what would be the probability for the second ace to be right after the first ace?
I saw the answer is 1/13 but I couldn't understand why.

Comment: Please clarify this problem.  Are the cards spread in a row, or in an array?  What does "first" ace mean?  Are we turning the cards over in some order?

Comment: you have a deck of 52 cards, and you put all the cards on table, one by one. what would be the probability of getting an ace and right after that another ace?
no special order, the cards are spread in a row.

Comment: for the first ace it doesn't matter, I agree. but it matters that the second ace will be beside it.so why is it 1\13?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: I think he means a regular deck of $52$ cards, that is, containing four aces, four twos, four threes etc.

Comment: yes it is a regular deck of cards, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to consider a simpler problem:

What is the probability that the first ace is the ace of spades and the second ace immediately follows it?

To compute this probability, count the number of ways in which the above event can occur. Towards that end, note there are $51!$ ways to arrange the $51$ cards that are not the ace of spades. For each of these orderings, there is only one way to place the ace of spades. So there are $51!$ orderings in which the second ace immediately follows the ace of spades.

So the probability is $51!/52!=1/52$.

Now note the above case is one of four mutually exclusive cases whose union is exactly the event you're interested in.

Comment: Nice. $~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [indeed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i%3D0+to+48+of+12%2aFactorialPower%5B48%2Ci%5D%2FFactorialPower%5B52%2Ci%2B2%5D) $\frac{1}{13}$.  I calculated $$\sum_{i=0}^{48}\frac{(48)_i(4)_2}{(52)_{i+2}}=\frac{4}{52}\frac{3}{51}+\frac{48}{52}\frac{4}{51}\frac{3}{50}+\frac{48}{52}\frac{47}{51}\frac{4}{50}\frac{3}{49}+\cdots=\frac{1}{13}$$

While I'm sure there's a nice combinatorial proof, it eludes me at the moment.

Comment: Can you please explain the answer?

Comment: The $i^\textrm{th}$ term corresponds to the probability of $i$ non-aces, followed by two aces.

Comment: what does this mean (48)i?

Comment: $(x)_n=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n+1)$ is the [falling factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).